# Delete rows using SSIS

Tags: ssis, lookup

I am creating a package that maintains rows of data in a destination table synchronized with the source. What I do is to do a copy first of all the rows that do not exist in the destination using a lookup. For instance, both my tables have an ID and lets say that at a moment in time they look like this:

Source: Id(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

Destination: Id(4,7,6,9)

Right now I am using in the Lookup control the setting "Redirect rows to no match output." As a result, in this specific case, I would get 1,2,3,5 and those rows is what I would copy to the destination. What I also would like to do (in a different step or same step does not matter) is to also get the number 9 from the destination and delete it. The reason being that it does not exist any longer in the source. I have been experimenting with the same Lookup control; however I cannot get it to work. I am new to this tool and I may not be using the right control for this scenario. So if there is a different way to do this, that would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by doing the reverse lookup.

For example, for inserts you do the following:

1. OLE Source Table
2. Lookup (Destination Table)
3. Lookup No Match Output
4. OLE Source Destination

For Deletes, you follow the reverse lookup:

1. OLE Destination Table
2. Lookup (Source Table)
3. Lookup No Match Output
4. OLE Command - DELETE FROM  WHERE id=?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a SQL statement in Execute SQL task. I've added the demo results below to show you how this works.#temp is your Source Id and #temp2 the destination ID/ Try adapting the following SQL :

```
select * from dbo.#temp
select * from dbo.#temp2

select b.one
from #temp2 b left join #temp a
on a.one = b.one
where a.one is null 

Delete b from #temp2 b left join #temp a
on a.one = b.one where a.one is null

select * from #temp2 order by one
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just getting started with SSIS for ETL. Came looking for ideas about how to handle rows that are deleted in source. Liked this suggestion but modified it slightly to update the target row to show it is no longer active so that I can preserve historical data in my data warehouse:

```
UPDATE #temp2
SET End_Date = GetDate(),[Current] = 0
WHERE BusinessKey = 
(
SELECT b.BusinessKey
FROM #temp2 b LEFT JOIN #temp a
ON a.BusinessKey = b.BusinessKey
WHERE a.BusinessKey IS null
)
```